# What's the best site to ask a question about Adobe Illustrator, superuser, or graphic design?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I see a lot of questions on superuser.com regarding illustrator but it seems more like illustrator questions should be asked in graphicdesign.stackexchange.com instead.

What's your thought on that?

Specifically, where do you think the following question belongs?
[In Adobe Illustrator, How do you paste an item to the BOTTOM of the layer stack, not the top?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/1563/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When in doubt, compare the FAQs!

> Graphic's Design - Stack Exchange is for questions targeted towards 2-d design professionals, students, and enthusiasts. This includes questions about:
>
> - Graphic arts - logo design, fonts & typography, visual communication, etc.
> - Web design
> - Layout and printing
> - illustration
> - Digital media - (i.e., Flash, Video)
>
> it is not about ...
>
> - Technical questions related to 3D software
> - Technical suggestions related to Video editing software
> - Web site architecture and development (i.e., pure HTML/no CSS, questions related to the back end)
> - Landscaping and Architecture

Compared to [SuperUser's FAQ](https://superuser.com/faq), this definitely sounds more like what you want unless it's a question about installing the software or issues with the software itself and not how to use features of the software.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That's what I was thinking too. I've updated the question above with a sample question. WHere do you think it belongs?

Comment: @trusktr I'd say that's more GD's purview than SuperUser, or at the very least the community at GD (smaller though it may be) is more likely to be familiar with the ins and outs of Illustrator to help.

Answer (score 2):

If it's about the design aspect, definitely Graphic Design.

If it's more about the "using an application" aspect (like, uninstalling or getting it to run on a certain OS), Super User.