# Is there an Adobe stackexchange site

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Question is self explanatory. Is there an Adobe stack exchange site? Couldn't find any.

I can see adobe questions on various sites like Stack Overflow and superuser and on Graphics but I want to know if there is a site dedicated for all adobe products.

Comment: Related: [What's the best site to ask a question about Adobe Illustrator, superuser, or graphic design?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/85922/295232)

Answer (score 4):

No, there is no Adobe site and I'm not sure if such site would thrive in the Q/A format and the communities that attend to such sites.

Sites in the SE network focus on specific knowledge so it can attract and maintain a healthy community of experts to answer and curate the posts on the subject. A Q/A site for Adobe, besides being a support magnet, seems overly broad given the product range of Adobe. Instead ask a question or find the experts that focus on the use of tools to solve a particular problem or achieve a specific goal in a specific area/skill. The various sites around the network do that, hence the multiple sites result when you search for the [`[adobe]`](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Badobe%5D) tag.

If you still feel an Adobe site is valuable to have with an useful collection of curated knowledge in the form of Question and Answers you can propose such site on [Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/faq).  From there you can determine its scope and invite the needed experts to back the proposal. With enough sample questions and followers the site might go into beta.

An other (extra?)option might be to approach Adobe and ask them to do a [sponsorship](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/307861/158100) although I have to warn you that the driving force behind that idea no longer works for Stack Exchange and I'm only aware of one or two of these kind of sponsorships that actually took off.

Comment: Too Broad a topic -Really ? Then what about Superuser ? That covers every type of computer and OS in existence (and some that are no longer in existence) and that site seems pretty successful.

Comment: @Kevin true, but Super User tries to attract this audience *computer enthusiasts and power users*. That is still pretty focused.

Comment: @rene maybe worth mentioning partnership option? Think SE started a while ago to check that option with some big enough companies, then the company actually sponsor the site.